# How to add Authorization header in azure blob storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-storage

I want to upload video to azure blob storage using its JavaScript client library. I have the SAS token from the API and I have created an instance for blob service like this:

```
var blobUri = 'https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/';
vm.sasTOken = "?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=abcdefghhi&st=2017-10-12T07%3A10%3A05Z&se=2017-10-12T11%3A10%3A05Z&sp=rl"
var blobService = AzureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, vm.sasToken);
```

I have tried to upload a video with this service

```
speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('containerName', vm.file.name, vm.file, { blockSize: customBlockSize}, function (error, result, response) {
   if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
```

I don't know where to pass the Authorization Headers that why its giving me error in console.

**403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)**

Comment: Can you share what your SAS token looks like? More than likely you have an invalid SAS token.

Comment: Its like this 
?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=rtPk88o2Y%2BpgFSk6JlJX8dPVUfx%2FhSfXkhQEDgyAn%2F8%3D&st=2017-10-12T06%3A55%3A09Z&se=2017-10-12T10%3A55%3A09Z&sp=rl

Comment: Thanks! In order for uploading file in a blob container, the SAS token should have `Write` permission. From the SAS token you shared, it seems you only included `Read` and `List` permission. Please create a SAS token with `Write` permission and try again.

Comment: @GauravMantri The write permission is already there in the token i have checked.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the following things: 1) value for blobUri (you can replace actual account name with a dummy string 2) value for `containerName` you are passing in `createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile` function and 3) value for `vm` variable that you're getting back from your API. You can replace the actual signature value in your SAS token with a dummy string.

Comment: Also please ensure that you have configured CORS rules properly.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156525/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-ahmer-khan).

Comment: @GauravMantri I have the SAS token with permissions and CORS, but still i am getting this error.

Comment: Can you please share the code for generating the SAS Token (I am interested in knowing for which container you're generating the SAS) and the name of the container in which you're uploading the file? Also, please share the CORS settings as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more thing:

The *start* and *expiry* date/time in the SAS token should be UTC time, not local time.

Please renew the SAS token and ensure these values are not out of the valid range of date/time in UTC.